# Debug.Log()/Print()/UnityEngine.Debug.Log() not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, virtual-reality, oculus

My project is working with Oculus Quest 2 and Virtual Reality. I am writing a script that should detect when the hand collides with a game object. The script isn't working so I tried adding some Debug.Log() statements to isolate the problem but they don't print to the console. Any advice on these problems is appreciated

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class colliderHit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myHand;
    public GameObject menuItem;
    public GameObject sublevel;
    public GameObject topMenu;
    Collider menuItemCollider;
    Collider myHandCollider;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(menuItem != null)
        {
            menuItemCollider = menuItem.GetComponent<Collider>();
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Menu Item not null");
        }
        else
        {
            print("Menu Item null");
        }

        if (myHand != null)
        {
            myHandCollider = myHand.GetComponent<Collider>();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Hand Item null");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (myHandCollider.bounds.Intersects(menuItemCollider.bounds))
        {
            topMenu.SetActive(false);
            sublevel.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("Bounds intersecting");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: stupid question maybe: Is this script attached to anything in your scene? Have you tried to [Debug your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)?

Comment: The script is definitely attached to a game object in my scene. I have tried filling the code with debug.log() statements but none of theme seem to print to the console

Comment: @LindaToomey Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Ruzihm unfortunately not. I'm almost sure the issue is that the script never gets called but I don't know why or how to fix that

Comment: this might be a silly question - is this component **enabled** on the object it is attached to? Are the object it is attached to and every ancestor of the object in the hierarchy active? There really is not enough information to reproduce the problem, which is required for debugging questions on SO. For unity questions, steps on how to set up the scene and hierarchy are required. See [mre] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you didn't disable messages in the console log? I only ask this because I tend to forget about that as well

[image: example console]

Comment: I didn't intentionally do this. How do I check this? Do you mean the symbols in the top right corner ?

Comment: There are three icons above the console that look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/5oWlZS8). The one on the left should be turned on to see print statements

Comment: @sighetsomeone I included a diagram to show what you are referring to

Comment: Well if it is this then also make sure there is nothing in the search bar like invisible space etc

Comment: I definitely have them all enabled so it's not that. I think it's possible that the script is just never being called which is strange because it is attached to a gameobject and the print statements are in the start method